# Error while uploading the sketch to Arduino UNO using CLI

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, raspberrypi, arduino-cli

I have connected my Arduino UNO through USB to Raspberry pi 3B. I am using CLI for editing, compiling and uploading sketches >  `arduino-cli upload --fqbn arduino:avr:uno cli-test`. However, after attempting to upload the sketch, it throws the error, `Error during Upload: Failed uploading: no upload port provided` I even checked if the Arduino is detected on the respective port using `arduino-cli board list` and it shows

```
/dev/ttyACM0 serial   Serial Port (USB) Arduino Uno arduino:avr:uno arduino:avr
/dev/ttyAMA0 serial   Serial Port       Unknown
```

The [support forum](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360020831120-Error-2-UNKNOWN-uploading-error-no-upload-port-provided) of Arduino says to 'select' the port. Nevertheless the support forum resolves the error for GUI application and not for CLI. I searched for how to select the port in CLI, but in vain. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.23/getting-started/#compile-and-upload-the-sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the port with the `--port` flag to the upload command:

```bash
$ arduino-cli upload --fqbn arduino:avr:uno --port /dev/ttyACM0 cli-test
```

You can find all these things out for yourself by using `--help` at any time. For example:

```bash
$ arduino-cli upload --help
Upload Arduino sketches. This does NOT compile the sketch prior to upload.

Usage:
  arduino-cli upload [flags]

Examples:
  arduino-cli upload /home/user/Arduino/MySketch

Flags:
      --board-options strings        List of board options separated by commas. Or can be used multiple times for multiple options.
      --discovery-timeout duration   Max time to wait for port discovery, e.g.: 30s, 1m (default 1s)
  -b, --fqbn string                  Fully Qualified Board Name, e.g.: arduino:avr:uno
  -h, --help                         help for upload
      --input-dir string             Directory containing binaries to upload.
  -i, --input-file string            Binary file to upload.
  -p, --port string                  Upload port address, e.g.: COM3 or /dev/ttyACM2
  -P, --programmer string            Programmer to use, e.g: atmel_ice
  -l, --protocol string              Upload port protocol, e.g: serial
  -t, --verify                       Verify uploaded binary after the upload.

Global Flags:
      --additional-urls strings   Comma-separated list of additional URLs for the Boards Manager.
      --config-file string        The custom config file (if not specified the default will be used).
      --format string             The output format for the logs, can be: text, json, jsonmini, yaml (default "text")
      --log-file string           Path to the file where logs will be written.
      --log-format string         The output format for the logs, can be: text, json
      --log-level string          Messages with this level and above will be logged. Valid levels are: trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal, panic
      --no-color                  Disable colored output.
  -v, --verbose                   Print the logs on the standard output.
```